# pandas take k entries from head and tail

Tags: python, pandas

how can I get `k` (let's say `100`) entries from a pandas.Dataframe from the head and tail of a dataframe? 
I would suggest 2 separate steps and a merge operation, but that seems tedious. Is there a better way?
I tried to use `df.iloc[:100,:-100]`, but that will only return the first 100 records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate indices:

```
N = 3
df = df.iloc[np.r_[0:N, -N:0]]
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(45)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,5)))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  3  0  5  3  4
1  9  8  1  5  9
2  6  8  7  8  5
3  2  8  1  6  4
4  8  4  6  4  9
5  1  6  8  8  1
6  6  0  4  9  8
7  0  9  2  6  7
8  0  0  2  9  2
9  6  0  9  6  0

N = 3
df = df.iloc[np.r_[0:N, -N:0]]
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  3  0  5  3  4
1  9  8  1  5  9
2  6  8  7  8  5
7  0  9  2  6  7
8  0  0  2  9  2
9  6  0  9  6  0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `iloc` with `range`

```
N = 3
df.iloc[range(0, N) + range(-N, 0)]
```

Details

```
In [200]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2))

In [201]: df
Out[201]:
          0         1
0 -1.034025  0.222752
1  0.102861 -0.827097
2  1.218721  0.397002
3  0.378780  1.903993
4  0.931718 -1.086045
5  1.608149 -0.233175
6 -1.399926 -2.218517
7 -0.411787  0.309623
8 -0.493428 -1.834097
9 -0.797647 -0.085315

In [202]: N = 3

In [203]: df.iloc[range(0, N) + range(-N, 0)]
Out[203]:
          0         1
0 -1.034025  0.222752
1  0.102861 -0.827097
2  1.218721  0.397002
7 -0.411787  0.309623
8 -0.493428 -1.834097
9 -0.797647 -0.085315
```

Comment: I get - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'

Comment: It works only in `python 2`, for python 3 need convert range to `list` like  `df.iloc[list(range(0, N)) + list(range(-N, 0))]`